# Is there a way to see the TLS cert details for a websocket connection in the Chrome console?

Tags: ssl, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

Client code makes a secure websocket connection to a site - I'd like to be able to open the developer console and look at the certificate that the site provided. We can do this for normal HTTPS websites by clicking on the lock icon next to the URL in the browser window, but I am not sure how to easily do this for WSS.